# Why gogen-avro generated container fails to deal with optional fields?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro

I have a Go consumer and producer. And the following schema:

```json
{
  "namespace" : "lets.see.how.it.works",
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "DataItem",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "basics",
    "type": {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Basics",
      "fields" : [
        {"name" : "id", "type" : "string"},
        {"name" : "value", "type" : ["null" , "string"]},
        {"name" : "alwaysNil", "type" : ["null" , "string"]}
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "extra",
    "type": ["null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "Extra",
      "fields" : [
        {"name" : "foo", "type" : ["null" , "string"], "default": "null"},
        {"name" : "boo", "type" : ["null" , "string"], "default": "null"}
      ]
    }],
    "default": "null"
  }, {
    "name" : "payload",
    "type": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "Payload",
      "fields": [
        {"name" : "val1", "type" : [ "null", "double" ], "default": "null"},
        {"name" : "val2", "type" : [ "null", "double" ], "default": "null"}
      ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

Then I generated classes using `gogen-avro`:

```
 gogen-avro --package=avro  ./internal/avro ./internal/avro/data-item-two.avsc
```

When I send a message without some fields that are optional my consumer with the same schema fails to parse it. For example (I see this message in `kcat`):

```json
{
    "basics": {
        "id": "2022-04-12T06:12:31Z",
        "value": {"string": "50"},
        "alwaysNil": null
    },
    "extra": {
        "Extra": {
            "foo": {"string": "Foo"},
            "boo": null
        }
    },
    "payload": {
        "val1": {"double": 0.5},
        "val2": null
    }
}
```

When consumer gets the message I try do deserialise it using `DeserializeDataItem()` I get an error `EOF`. What is also suspicious is that when it compiles decoder basing on schema `compiler.CompileSchemaBytes` returns deserialiser with errors `Unsupported type for union`. But returns `nil`.

Is there any ideas what's wrong with this schema?